# Is there a way to fix a Watchdog sump pump float sensor that is stuck on?

Tags: sump-pump

I came home after 2 weeks to hear my pump running.  The 10 year old Model BWC1 Watchdog dual float replacement sump pump controller was stuck on.  The float mechanism looks clean, perhaps a bit dusty. (I do not recall it having to turn on the pump in the past.)  I've washed off the dual float device in a sink but it is still stuck in the on position.

Any ideas how to get it out of the on position?

Update: The controller box case seems to be a little melted (see photo). So perhaps it is not the float device that is broken.  I guess I need to buy a new set.

Update: I called the manufacturer and was told the problem was probably caused by a spike in the 110v circuit.  (I've heard that type of explanation before and it is plausible but not convincing.)  The mfg suggested replacing the unit.

[image: Photo of controller box with what appears to be a melted part on the centre left hand side of the top panel.]

Comment: There are completely solid state (no moving parts) sump pump switches out there that I've found to be much reliable than the float types.  They're not cheap - retail for around $90 when I bought mine several years ago.

Answer (score 3):

It appears the contacts were bad and got hot then welded together.  They are probably located under the damaged plastic. You can choose to clean them, possibly file them, no guarantees if it will be a reliable repair. The best and safest solution is to simply replace it.